# Custom Mesh Mapping for a Sphere

Tags: java, mapping, textures, customization, mesh

I'm developping my own solar system simulation and I have trouble creating a sphere and ampping with the rigth index and vertices.
I'm currently developping in Java using Jmonkey3D.
I'm not sure where I did wrong but I think is in the creation of the mapping.

This is the code where i create the sphere (vertices,indices and the triangles):

```
public void creatingSphere(){
    Vector3f[] vertices_aus;
    Vector2f[] normals_aus;
    short[] mapping_aus;
    Punto v1, v2, v3, v4;
    int quad=0;
    int indexVertices=0;
    double lat,lon;
    int width=300;
    int height=300;
    double radius=1;
    vertices_aus=new Vector3f[((width*height)/4)*4];
    normals_aus=new Vector2f[((width*height)/4)*4];
    mapping_aus=new short[((width*height)/4)*6];
    
    int x;
    int y;
    
    for ( x = 0; x < width/4; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < height/4; y++) {
            //-------------------1° VERTICES----------------------
            lat=360*((4*y)+0)/(height/4);
            lon=360*((4*x)+0)/(width/4);
            v1 = new Punto();
            v1.x = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lon))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
            v1.y = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lon))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
            v1.z = radius *Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat));
            vertices_aus[indexVertices]=new Vector3f((float)v1.x, (float)v1.y, (float)v1.z);
            indexVertices++;
            
            normals_aus[(quad*(4))+0]=new Vector2f((y+0)*(1f/(width/4)),(x+0)*(1f/(height/4)));


            //-------------------2° VERTICES-----------------------
            
            lat=360*((4*y)+0)/(height/4);
            lon=360*((4*x)+1)/(width/4);
            v2 = new Punto();
            v2.x = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lon))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
            v2.y = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lon))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
            v2.z = radius *Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat));
            vertices_aus[indexVertices]=new Vector3f((float)v2.x, (float)v2.y, (float)v2.z);
            indexVertices++;
            normals_aus[(quad*(4))+1]=new Vector2f((y+1)*(1f/(width/4)),(x+0)*(1f/(height/4)));

            //-------------------3° VERTICES-----------------------
            
            lat=360*((4*y)+1)/(height/4);
            lon=360*((4*x)+0)/(width/4);
            v3 = new Punto();
            v3.x = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lon))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
            v3.y = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lon))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
            v3.z = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat));
            vertices_aus[indexVertices]=new Vector3f((float)v3.x, (float)v3.y, (float)v3.z);
            indexVertices++;
            normals_aus[(quad*(4))+2]=new Vector2f((y+0)*(1f/(width/4)),(x+1)*(1f/(height/4)));

            //-------------------4° VERTICES-----------------------
            
            lat=360*((4*y)+1)/(height/4);
            lon=360*((4*x)+1)/(width/4);
            v4 = new Punto();
            v4.x = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lon))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
            v4.y = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lon))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(lat));
            v4.z = radius *Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat));
            vertices_aus[indexVertices]=new Vector3f((float)v4.x, (float)v4.y, (float)v4.z);
            indexVertices++;
            normals_aus[(quad*(4))+3]=new Vector2f((y+1)*(1f/(width/4)),(x+1)*(1f/(height/4)));

            //---------------------TRIANGLES--------------------------
            mapping_aus[(quad*6)+0]=(short)((quad*(4))+2);
            mapping_aus[(quad*6)+1]=(short)((quad*(4))+0);
            mapping_aus[(quad*6)+2]=(short)((quad*(4))+1);
            mapping_aus[(quad*6)+3]=(short)((quad*(4))+1);
            mapping_aus[(quad*6)+4]=(short)((quad*(4))+3);
            mapping_aus[(quad*6)+5]=(short)((quad*(4))+2);
            
            quad++;
        }
    }
    
    this.setBuffer(Type.Position, 3, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices_aus));
    this.setBuffer(Type.TexCoord, 2, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(normals_aus));
    this.setBuffer(Type.Index,    1, BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(mapping_aus));
    this.updateBound();
}
```

and here is the result:

[result of the planet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGexT.png)

I already tried to search her on stack overflow and online to find a good example of how create such mesh but for Jmonkey3d seems that most of the help is lost and everyone is using blender but i prefer an old school approach and i want to generate the mesh in a dynamic way.
I hope that someone will help me.

Comment: That's a bit of a wall-o-code you're expecting people to diagnose, you're unlikely to get many responses.  Couple of suggestions: 1. Focus on breaking down the problem into manageable chunks.  E.g. You have roughly the same code for the calculation of the normals duplicated in three places, any one of which might be part of the problem - factor that out to a helper method and test that it behaves as expected.  Ditto for the lat/long calculations, vertex creation, etc.  2. Replace the texture coords with flat colours so it's easier to see what's being rendered.

Comment: Thanks to remind me that, I will focus on what part of my code and I if had to be bak I'll make a more focused question.
I did already some test after reading your post and I think the main problem is in the calculation of the vertices that now, with a proper texture, shows a strange but more sense pattern.